# Is it possible to change an inherited access modifier in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm currently working on a project where I have a ton of classes inheriting from other classes which inherit from other classes and so on. It's probably more complex than it should be, but I am a sucker for abstraction.

Anyway, at times I need to change a getter/setter from being public to private. I suppose it's not really a need, but a desire to cut off things that are preset in child classes, but still need to be publicly accessible in the parent classes.

So an example would be:

```
Class Base {
    public function set label( value:String ):void{};
}

Class A extends Base {}

Class B extends A {
    public function B() {
        super();
        this.label = "stuff";
    }

    override public function set label( value:String ):void {
        //this setter should not be publicly available since the label should not be possible to change in this class
    }
}
```

Currently, I am doing one of two things in these cases:

1. override the setter to do nothing or set it to the default value so that it can still update/render/whatever
2. throw an error saying it is unavailable in that class

I've done some searching and everything seems to point to this being impossible, but I've never found it explicitly stated that it is impossible. So is it possible to change the access modifier on an inherited property/function?

Comment: Seems like a design issue. If I was using a class that was inheriting from another class I had used before, I would expect all of the information from the base class to still be accessible via the class extending it. I would get a little confused if all of a sudden information that should be there wasn't; and I would get especially confused if that information was still listed as a class member but simply didn't return what I expected.

Comment: @MartyWallace That is very true. It is definitely an issue with my design and I am working on fixing the issue (caused by having a less than a month to do 2-3 months of work and cutting some corners), but I am still curious if this is possible or not.

Comment: Unfortunately it is definitely not possible to do. I searched for a while to try and have similar things like an internal setter and public getter but with no luck.

Comment: @MartyWallace That's what I figured. It's a shame, really, as there are times where I could see it being good design to cut off access or to do the opposite and switch a private modifier to public. And I have tried the internal setter/public getter thing as well. That one disappointed me too.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is using your own namespace (like they do with "mx_internal" in the Flex framework), and the plain old `internal` namespace (which makes the property accessible to other classes in the same package). But given your current design, it's likely these won't fit neatly into your hierarchy of classes.

Comment: @SunilD. I don't think a custom namespace would get around this problem and would just add complexity to the issue, although I do like the idea. It's a creative solution that I've never considered before. I think I'll take a look at the mx_internal source to see how you go about this. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible, and it really should not be, because it leads to confusing and unpredictable class hierarchies. For starters, if you did something like that, you would break the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): A super class should at all times be replaceable by its derived classes. Changing the API would clearly prevent that - and thus possibly lead to runtime errors and/or inexplicable glitches, if another programmer accidentally exchanged types.

If the classes you are modeling have different behavior in such a way that would make you "hide" an otherwise public API method, you should probably not use inheritance for this - or perhaps in a different way. From what you are describing, I would guess that in a larger part of your hierarchy, you should probably be using composition instead of inheritance, anyway.

Comment: These are very good points. It is definitely poor design on my part, but it was what I managed to throw together in the time I had been given. What is happening here is I create a component class and then its children are the "skins" (I'm using pure AS3 as opposed to Flex or another framework to keep things as light weight as humanly possible). If I had had more time, I would have created a basic skinning framework to use, but instead I am using this. Regardless, I think you answered my question very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for the very reason in the comments by *Marty Wallace*. But it's not an uncommon thing to do.

However in the alternative you used, The property owner is the base class & hence it should always know of anything that the derived class does with it's own properties.

Instead of your hack I would thus prefer something like this :

```
public class Base   {
        protected var _isLabelUsable:Boolean = true;

        public function set label( value:String ):void {
            if (!_isLabelUsable)
                throw new Error("Access of undefined property label.");

            // Set Label here
        }
    }

public class A extends Base {

}

public class B extends A {      
        public function B() {
            super();            
            _isLabelUsable = false; 
        }       
    }
```

Comment: That's not a bad way of going about it. This way it is all a function of the base class. And you could create a read-only getter for the `usable` properties so that other classes could see if they were usable or not. I may use this pattern for something else, honestly. I'll avoid using it for this purpose (as it is a poor practice), but it could be useful in other places.

Answer (score 0):

These are all valid points, but...
There are cases where they are all void.
Given a base class that comes from an external source. Like, say, mx:Panel.
It has the property 'titleIcon:Class'
The derived class inherits all properties and functions. But people using it shall never set the titleIcon directly, because part of the derived class' functionality depends on the availability of an icon name being known. It provides a property iconName:String. Setting it will also set the titleIcon.
Now how to prevent people from still setting the icon directly? The UI is offering the old property for AS3 and MXML, and the compiler will (of course) not complain.

If titleIcon is a setter/getter pair (in this case, it is), and not final, then the derived class can override the setter and throw an error, while the iconName setter will assign the icon class to super.titleIcon.
However, this is clumsy and will not work for final functions or variables.

If there were a way to at least tell the UI to not offer the property anymore or show a warning...